# Making gallery responsive with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am trying to build simple gallery.
What I would like to achieve is this:

[image]

However, what I am actually achieving is this:
[image]

There is basically too much space between images and I can't find a way how to solve it. I understand that is because of `justify-content: space-between;` but perhaps there's another option that will put less space between the images?

Html

```
<div class="photoContainer>
   <div class="ant-image">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.photosContainer {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
}

.ant-image {
    height: fit-content;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: Maybe `justify-content: flex-start;`

Comment: @skobaljic yeah that fix the problem but create new one that i get no spaces. And when i try to use some fixed margin it looks bad when i am changing size of browser because it leaves often blank space on right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use grid display instead of flex and solve your problem:

```
.photosContainer{
       display:grid;
       grid-template-columns:repeat(4 , 1fr);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks it looks that it can be used very well regards this article https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5295881-create-web-page-layouts-with-css/5369951-set-columns-depending-on-screen-size.

Answer (score 2):

With the space-between rule you cannot have the control of the space between the images.
My suggestion is to:

- make the image gallery container smaller because you have a small number of photos
- to have more control over the images you can use also for the single image a % width as you have done for the container.

hint: use property object-fit for the single images